# Open a SlideView picture with a Markerclicklistener

Tags: google-maps-markers, slideshow, onclicklistener

How can i open a slideview picture by clicking on a marker in the map? 
I already try to put the viewPager on a popupwindow, but didn't work. please help

MapsActiviy

```
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);



            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.map), Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            return false;
        }
    });
```